# How to set multiple div side by side without space between them

Tags: css

I need to construct something like this: https://youtu.be/-pv77UW1w6g
But I'm facing problems to set div side by side with no space between them.

I made a wireframe to help to show my idea like the video above: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9095670/multiple-divs.jpg

It's important to say that I'm using bootstrap and it's a responsive project. So, I don't want use fixed width or heigh (if possible) to do that. I've tried use display: inline, but I got many holes between them due the fixed min-height.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Look into [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: My current code is (this is a loop):

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="thumbnail box-user-posts">
                <img src="assets/images/avatar-404.jpg"/><div class="caption">
                                <a href="#">
                                  <H4>
                                    Title
                                  </H4>
                                </a>
                                <p class="text-small" ></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the fact that you markup likely has whitespace between the elements, the simplest way to avoid this is to set font-size: 0px; in the document body, then add a class to each child div that re-sets the font size back to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="children">1</div>
<div class="children">2</div>
<div class="children">3</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PPEqJm

Comment: Thanks, Damiano, but it's not work well :(
The height can't be fixed. I tried remove the height and fill with different content in each div to simulate different sizes, but the div still side by side, even if I set the width on wrap to 500px for example, and them do not break the row to stay above the firsts.

Comment: @ andre
Give me a couple minutes i will construct a nice one for you, where you can see how useful thr flexbox model is for what you want, it just needs a bit explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go.
You can comment out the keyframes, but I have put a bit animation in it, your video made me:-).
To explain this...as you see, there is no height declaration on the divs, only on the main wrapper div. And on the img tags, for demo purposes.
As you can see the divs will adapt height to whatever content is placed in to them.
Same for the pictures, you make them the size you want.
With the flexbox layout as it is there, I make the divs being placed as column, i.e. vertically. There is a height declaration on the main div, this one you will need if you want to display it like this, but only this one, without a height on main div, flexbox would never create a next column, it would just stack them one over the next. 
This way, as soon the height is reached, it creates a new horizontal column. This would be possible in other ways as well and takes some understanding of the flexbox model, do look into it, i thinks it is the future of layout.
And you set a width on the children class, i set it to 30% here, for 3 rows(flex will still create a 4th,5th etc, but these would fall out of the wrap div, so, a bit calculation is needed on your part.

Play around with it and see what happens if you change the children class width, or put more/less text in it, careful with margin, margin is bit odd with flexbox, this is beyond the scope here though.
Do not be afraid when flexbox creates a new row, don't try to fix it with margins when it looks odd(new or od row having a gap etc, you will see what i mean).
And this will be fully responsive as it is.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes bro{
1% {transform: skew(5deg, 6deg);}
25%  {transform: skew(10deg, 5deg);}
75%  {transform: skew(15deg,9deg);}
90% {transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0.1);}
}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PPEqJm

If you have any question, ask anytime.

Comment: @Wobbles, that is true, but it is a very tiresome procedure and there will still be potential cross browser issues, i have decided to use flexbox whenever i can. Sure, flexbox can have its own issues too.
Btw, Andre, i have set some margin there deliberately, you can remove it, it will still be ok, but your example vid had margins too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help, but I solved my problem with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) as [hungerstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804867/hungerstar) said. The Masonry is good if you're using Angular.js too.